# Get RowHeader Text in SpreadJs

Tags: spreadjs

I want to get the row header text, after clicking on any specific row. It could be number/alphabet. Yes, I'm able to get its index. But I want to get its text value, which i'm needed to show elsewhere in my case. I didn't found any idea or solution in its documentation page [Get Sheet Header](http://spread.grapecity.com/Demos/JS/TutorialSample/#/samples/sheetHeader). Hope, there's any way to figure out this problem. Thanks for any solution/advice.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should tell us what you already tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the row header text by using getCell and passing in the SheetArea.rowHeader variable.  Here is how to do it on a cell click (or header click):

```js
activeSheet.bind(GcSpread.Sheets.Events.CellClick, function (sender, args) {
    if (args.sheetArea === GcSpread.Sheets.SheetArea.rowHeader) {
        alert("Row header text: " + activeSheet.getCell(args.row, args.col, GcSpread.Sheets.SheetArea.rowHeader).value());
    }
});
```

Let me know if that helps.

Regards,
Kevin